# Converting NRRD file to JPG

Tags: python, image-processing

i am trying to convert nrrd file into jpg by reading that nrrd image using pynrrd and then using the pixel i am trying to form an image but the out i am getting is terrible contrast image. Below is waht i have tried

```
import numpy as np
import nrrd
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
filename = "/content/drive/MyDrive/CT.nrrd"
readdata, header = nrrd.read(filename)
print(readdata.shape) # (512, 512, 504)
for i in range(504):
  if i == 200:
    img = np.array(readdata[:,:,i])
    print(img.shape)
    print(np.amax(img))
    img = (np.maximum(img, 0) / img.max()) * 255.0
    img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(img), mode = "L")
    img.save(f'/content/testrgb{i}.png')
    break
```

The output i am getting is this [image]

Can someone please help me this

Comment: You might consider sharing your NRRD file - possibly with Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: you're expecting the bone to be the brightest object... but it's not. there's some piece of debris on the right, which is brightest. -- perhaps you might wanna use 99th percentile level or something based on mean and standard deviation, instead of _the maximum_

Comment: Thank you for the response @MarkSetchell and Christoph. i am attaching my answer which solved my problem but I did with manually changing the contrast value of the image but it is working on almost all nrrd file. Could you please look at my answer and see if this is okay or it can get better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import nrrd

```
def manipulating_nrrd_contrast(img, level):
    img_c = img.astype(int).copy()
    factor = (8 * (level+255)) / (255 * (259-level)) #This 8 here is the value that i changes manually by try and test and found out that this works best 
    img_c = factor * (img_c - 128) + 128
    img_c = np.clip(img_c, 0, 255)
    return img_c.astype(np.uint8)

filename = "/content/drive/MyDrive/CT.nrrd"
readdata, header = nrrd.read(filename)
tag_info = get_meta_data(header)
print(tag_info)
print(readdata.shape)
for i in range(readdata.shape[2]):
  b = np.asarray(readdata[:,:,i]).astype(int)
  final = Image.fromarray(manipulating_nrrd_contrast(b, 128))
  final.save(f'/content/png/testrgb{i}.png')
```

And, The Result that i got is below
[image]